# Small dot trailing cursor in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, cursor

There is a small dot that keeps trailing the cursor on a Swing application as I move the cursor about over the application frame.  What is causing this?

Comment: You're using Windows, or something else? A remote desktop or VNC connection?

Comment: I've seen this as well and have never found a solution (haven't looked real hard either). In my experience the dot is one pixel by one pixel and seems to be anchored near the lower right corner of the cursor - but the distance from the cursor seems to vary. I don't have an answer for you, just contributing the circumstances I've seen.

Comment: same thing is happening to me. anybody know what this dot on the cursor is?

Comment: I keep getting the dot on login windows for Livejournal, Facebook and various websites.  I actually am getting it in the upper right of my cursor.  

It's pretty annoying.  I've wondered if this is some sort of keylogger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it be an empty tooltip?
Is the getTooltip() method implemented for the frame (or other component you are hovering over)? If you don't want the tooltip, you should return null, and not an empty String.